# Как сделать запросы на сервер грамотно

Tags: android, json, android-studio, retrofit2

У меня есть некие данные ( 5 строк и одно изображение) все это нужно отправить на сервер. Причем одна из этих строк должна содержать в себе адрес загруженного(на сервер) изображения. Как правильно организовать все это дело? Сначала сделать POST изображения, потом с помощью GET получить ее адрес и вставить в строку с последующим POST запросом этих строк, или есть более правильный способ? Все это будет работать на Android при помощи Retrofit

Comment: Было бы отлично если бы вы работали с изображением при его загрузке, но если это не подходит из-за вашей архитектуры то сначала грузите изображение + сохраняете на него ссылку и дальше уже 5 строк свои отправляете.

Comment: Дело в том, что изображение я получаю одновременно с текстом. Вернее сначала пользователь ставит себе аватарку(может отказаться) далее заполняет 5 строк с информацией о себе.

Comment: А зачем вам в этих 5 строках аватарка?

Comment: Я отправляю данные на restdb.io у них есть некий Media Archive куда можно загружать фото. И я планировал загрузить туда аватарку. И дальше когда эти строки буду вносить уже в JSON файл, в строку с изображением передать ссылку на аватарку

Comment: Если вы хотите реализовать post запрос с 5 строками, 1 из них - это ссылка на аву, то полная запись этих 5 строк в БД будет зависеть от скорости записи запросов: сначала post изображения на Media Archive , потом get его url с архива, потом только произойдет запись 5 строк. Т.е., если на Media Archive будет задержка, то она отразится на всей записи 5 строк. Есть вариант разбить запись, сначала отправляя 4 строки без URL авки, а потом уже и ее. Но, на самом деле не думаю, что такая проблема сильно повлияет на использование и чисто теоретически может быть вызвана при 1 регистрации.

Comment: @AlexGin у меня при первом вводе пользователя все добавляется в БД Room и отображается пользователю, ну а в следующий раз при входе БД обновится от Api

Comment: Тогда проблем особо не должно быть, если скорость получения первичных данных на сервере не имеет значения. Думаю, можно использовать вариант получения URL авы, а потом загрузку 5 строк

Comment: На счет реализации через room, у вас при регистрации есть поля, которые должны быть уникальными ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем реализовал так - если юзер решает ставить фото на заставку, тогда эта фотография асинхронно уходит на сервер, в ответ от сервера я получаю id изображения (ответ от `restdb.io` id фотографии загруженной в `Media Archive`) и вставляю его уже в одну из 5 строк и отправляю на сервер. Таким образом получается - `POST` -> `POST` вместо `POST` -> `GET` -> `POST`